# Windows 10 Multiple ethernet network connections

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, ethernet

I have a Windows 10 machine which is connected to two routers. Both supply IP addresses via DHCP.

One router is my ISP router. The other is a Linux (Debian) machine.

The Linux box is connected to the ISP router and obtains its IP address from the ISP router.

If I remove my network connection (physical ethernet wire) which connects the Windows 10 machine to the ISP router, Windows aquires an IP address from the Linux box and uses this to connect to the internet.

If I re-connect the wire, nothing happens.

If I then remove the wire between the Linux box and Windows, Windows will obtain and IP from the ISP router and connect to the internet this way.

I want to be able to connect to the Linux box via RDP when this machine is powered on. I can  do it by physically removing a wire, but this is a pain.

Is there a way to get Windows to try and connect to both networks without having to physically remove a cable to get it to "wake up" and "change over" to using a different network route?

Comment: Have the DHCP server on your linux machine not provide a gateway for your windows machine.

Comment: @Silbee Possibly - how would I check this?

Comment: @Silbee I'm not sure if that is the issue actually, since Windows doesn't seem to be asking for an IP address from this network interface. It doesn't have an IP right now

Comment: Are there 2 different physical routers ? And are both networks on a different subnet ?

Comment: @Silbee They are two different physical pieces of hardware. Both the Windows machine and the Linux machine connect to the ISP router on the network `192.168.0.0/24`, the network offered from the Linux machine to the Windows machine is on network `192.168.10.0`, which is a different network definition to the network defined by the ISP router.

Comment: Thanks for the added information. I'm a bit stumped as to why windows shows this kind of behaviour. The only thing i can think of is some kind of ARP caching issue. The last thing i can suggest would be would be to disconnect the linux box from the ISP router, restart windows, linux and router and see if windows-isp and windows-linux works fine without linux-isp being active.

Comment: @Silbee From your last comment I assume you would expect this to "just work"? Will try your suggestions later today, thanks for this

Comment: Windows does not like having multiple gateways! Change one of them to a completely different subnet and test it out with static IP addressing instead of DHCP.